# Manually set y axis tick labels in a facet wrap forest plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I'm producing a facet wrapped forest plot and I'd like to manually set the y-axis labels.

Here's my example data:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10),y=c(1:5,1:3,1:2),
                 group=c(rep("a",5),rep("b",3),rep("c",2)),
                 name=c(paste("a",1:5,sep=""),paste("b",1:3,sep=""),paste("c",1:2,sep="")))
df$xmin <- df$x-runif(10,0.5,0.7)
df$xmax <- df$x+runif(10,0.5,0.7)
```

And here's the code I'm trying:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df,aes(y = y, x = x))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_y_discrete(limits = df$name, expand = c(.1,0))+
  facet_wrap(~group,ncol=3,scales="free")+
  geom_segment(aes(x = xmin, xend = xmax, y = y, yend = y))+
  geom_vline(lty=2, aes(xintercept=0), colour = 'red')
```

Which produces this figure:

[image]

As you can see the y-axis tick labels of the middle and right most facets are not consistent with `df$name`.

Comment: Have you considered `facet_grid(.~group)` in place of `facet_wrap`?

Comment: I know it's an option but still hoping facet_wrap can work here

Comment: What particular feature of `facet_wrap` do you need? Is it the y-axis labels on each panel?

Comment: Yes. The y-axis labels in the middle facet should be: b1-b3 and in the right most facet: c1-c2

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot(df,aes(y = name, x = x)) + 
geom_point() + 
facet_wrap(~group,ncol=3,scales="free") + 
geom_segment(aes(x = xmin, xend = xmax, y = name, yend = name)) + 
geom_vline(lty=2, aes(xintercept=0), colour = 'red')
```